# Bluetooth on a read-only system

Tags: bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

Oi, I am trying to say hello here... why are you deleting my "Hello all"...
Anyway, as the title suggests, I need some help with bluetooth on a read only system. After some playing around and following various guides, I came to the conclusion that I need to pair my phone and the rpi while the system is RW and not RO. After that, even if it is RO it will work without any issues. So the question is, where is that list of paired devices physically located, is it possible to move it to a different place (like an RW folder). Otherwise I will need to temporarily mount my root folder as RW, pair and then change it back to RO.
Thank you for reading me.

Comment: Hello @papatrexas. So a) Jessie is pretty old (just a warning) b) You may find a list of the files used by `bluetoothd` here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/bluetoothd (and by typing `man bluetoothd` in the terminal).

Comment: Oh, thanks mate.I will probably do the same thing I've done with samba to work on RO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After user96931's suggestion, I did the following,
Made a folder named bluetooth in a partition that is ReadWrite (you need to have something like that)

```
sudo mkdir /home/bluetooth
```

Changed owner and perms

```
sudo chown nobody /home/bluetooth/

sudo chmod 777 /home/bluetooth/
```

Deleted the original /var/lib/bluetooth folder (didn't care about keeping any settings or paired devices)
Add a link from /home/bluetooth to /var/lib/bluetooth.

```
sudo ln -s /home/bluetooth/ /var/lib/bluetooth
```